# Why Spark-BigQuery connector creates temporary table when loading data from query?

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run some query on BQ, then load the result into Spark for further processing. I'm assuming this is a pretty common use case. [The upstream documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/README.md#reading-from-views) says this:

> Important: This feature is implemented by running the query on BigQuery and saving the result into a temporary table, of which Spark will read the results from.

I'm trying to build a proper mental model of how it all works, and this one doesn't compute for me. After all, when I use BQ directly, I do not "save the result into a temporary table" to read it.

When I look at [the jobs.getQueryResults()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) REST API, it seems to have all the capabilities needed to have Spark workers read different portions of the query result concurrently.

From [the documentation of JobConfigurationQuery.destinationTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery.FIELDS.destination_table), it seems like a query result is internally written to a table anyway.

I'm sure there's some reasons I'm missing, though. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the details of the BigQuery spark connector, but the normal reason this happens is to parallelize the data transfer.

Most Spark connectors can read in parallel from tables, which in Big Data sources are often file-based.  But reading the results of a query happens over a single network connection.

So spooling the results allows the Spark cluster workers to read the results in parallel, and this is one of the many ways Spark optimizes for scalability over speed or efficiency.

Also as you point out, query results may *always* be spooled to a file instead of being streamed to the client.  That's also common in Big Data sytems.